# Asp .NET required Field Validator chenge between two error messages based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

A drop down list with mandatory input field, but I have also to check on one particular value so I need to have two different error messages to swich between. 
So far It can display only the first option, not the second one (Please insert). Any suggestions?

```
 <div>
     <%if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFinalized.Text))
       {%> 
         <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" CssClass="stdLabel">Finalized Method<span class="mandatory"> *</span></asp:Label>
     <%}
       else
       {%> 
           <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" CssClass="stdLabel">Finalized Method </asp:Label>
    <% } %>   


      <%if (userRole == ("MS_Administrator") ||
            userRole == ("MS_Expert") ||
           (userRole == ("MS_User") && (txtOwner.Text == "" || txtOwner.Text.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper())))
         {%>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFinalizedMethod" runat="server" CssClass="stdDropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGxP_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="myTest()" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlFinalizedMethod" InitialValue="0" CssClass="RequiredFieldError" ErrorMessage=" !Please select another Standard"  />    
     <%}
       else  
        {%>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvFinalizedMethod" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlFinalizedMethod" InitialValue="0" OnServerValidate="cvFinalizedMethod_ServerValidate" CssClass="RequiredFieldError" Text="! Please insert"  />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFinalizedMethodDisabled" runat="server" CssClass="stdTextboxSmallDisabled" Enabled="true" />
        <% } %>    



  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using WebForms?  MVC?

Comment: I'm using WebForms

Comment: It would be much easier, more readable, and more manageable to have your HTML on the aspx and keep your server logic in the aspx.cs file.  Is there a reason you are writing your pages like this with everything intermingled?